# Is there a way to pre-configure variables for vscode debugging?

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, configuration, local-variables

I'm working on a python projects with multiple modules, each connected to a separate CLI. The project contains quite a bit of legacy code not written by me. Unfortunately an update of a dependency lead to some unexpected behavior, which i'm now trying to fix. To debug single modules more easily, I would like to pre-define some variables which usually would be passed by the CLI.

For development I usually use vscode and I would like to use the integrated debugger.

Here a minimal example of a python script:

Python example script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

a = 1
b = 2

def div(a,b):
    return a/b

output = div(a,b)
```

I would like to do is defining the variables a and b in the launch.json similar to the following example config, but instead of passing the variables to the CLI, passing them directly to the debugger (like typing in the debug console).

launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "set_python_variables",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": ["a=2","b=6"]
        }

    ]
}
```

So far I found out, that it is possible to set environment variables or pass command line args via launch.json. I'm also able to set variables in the debug console during debugging. Now I'm wondering, whether there is a way to pre-configure variables instead of adding them in the code or manually entering them in the debug console (defining a and b outside the code).

tl;dr: Is there a way to pre-configure variables instead of entering them manually in the debug console?

edit: Minimal example

Comment: have you looked at Pexpect?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're trying to achieve, some examples of your `launch.json` and how you change it might be of help. Anyway, it looks like you can try creating multiple configurations in `launch.json` for each of your cases and then select appropriate one in the Run panel. Another thing to consider is that environment variables in `launch.json` support [variables reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference). Still, not sure if it helps.

Comment: @NikolayK In short: I try to define local variables outside of the script. Instead off adding val="variableA" somewhere in the script, I was wondering whether it is possible to define it somewhere outside of the script (e.g. `launch.json`) for debugging only.